# Cómo hacer una clase el cual sume dos arreglos objetos de la misma clase en C++?

Tags: c++, poo, clase, class, math

Estoy haciendo una clase el cual se pueda sumar entre dos objetos de una misma clase, pero no sé cómo diseñarlo en C++.
Hasta ahora llevo lo siguiente (dandome error):

```
// Por seguridad, para comprobar después como operar arreglos

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class sumaArreglos{
  private:
    int arreglo[1000];
    int tamanio;
  public:
    sumaArreglos(){}
    ~sumaArreglos(){}
    void setArreglo(){
      cin>>tamanio;
      int numeroEntrada;
      for(int i=0; i<tamanio; i++){
        cin>>numeroEntrada;
        arreglo[i]=numeroEntrada;
      }
    }
    void accionSumar(int arreglo2[1000]){
      for(int i=0; i<tamanio; i++){
        arreglo[i] = arreglo[i] + arreglo2[i];
      }
    }
    void imprimir(){
      cout<<"{";
      for(int i=0; i<7; i++){
        cout<<arreglo[i]<<" ";
      }
      cout<<"}";
    }
};


int main() {
  sumaArreglos arreglo1;
  sumaArreglos arreglo2; // no sé por qué no me funciona cuando trato de que arreglo2 sea de la clase sumar arreglo

  arreglo1.setArreglo();
  cout<<"cambio"<<endl;
  arreglo1.setArreglo();

  arreglo1.accionSumar(arreglo2);

  arreglo1.imprimir();

  return 0;
  
}
```

Había comprobado antes que si uno hace que arreglo2 sea un arreglo de tipo de dato int (por ejemplo int arreglo2[10]={elementos int} el programa sí me funciona, pero necesito que 2 objetos de una misma clase puedan operarse entre sí.
Gracias por su ayuda.

Comment: No se si te estoy entendiendo, ¿Quieres que la expresión `sumaArreglos c = a + b` sea correcta donde `a` y `b` sean de tipo `sumaArreglos`?

Comment: sólo quiero que a = a+b, aunque crear otro objeto también es una buena idea

Comment: Me gustaría utilizar un objeto c = a + b, pero no tengo la suficiente pericia para poder implementarlo

Comment: Por favor, edita tu pregunta indicando exáctamente qué error te sale.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema es que estas definiendo como parámetro de entrada del método `accionSumar` un array de enteros y cuándo invocas el método le das un objeto de la clase que creaste, si quieres usar un objeto de tipo `sumaArreglos` como entrada del método, debes de cambiar `accionSumar` así:

```
void accionSumar(sumaArreglos arreglo2){
  for(int i=0; i<tamanio; i++){
    arreglo[i] = arreglo[i] + arreglo2.arreglo[i];
  }
}
```

Suerte programando! Espero que te sirva!

UPDATE:

El código final de pruebas me quedó así:

```
// Por seguridad, para comprobar después como operar arreglos

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class sumaArreglos{
  private:
    int arreglo[1000];
    int tamanio;
  public:
    sumaArreglos(){}
    ~sumaArreglos(){}
    void setArreglo(){
      cout<<"Digite el tamaño: "<<endl;
      cin>>tamanio;
      int numeroEntrada;
      for(int i=0; i<tamanio; i++){
        cout<<"Digite el elemento #"<<i<<endl;
        cin>>numeroEntrada;
        arreglo[i]=numeroEntrada;
      }
    }
    void accionSumar(sumaArreglos arreglo2){
      for(int i=0; i<tamanio; i++){
        arreglo[i] = arreglo[i] + arreglo2.arreglo[i];
      }
    }
    void imprimir(){
      cout<<"{";
      for(int i=0; i<7; i++){
        cout<<arreglo[i]<<" ";
      }
      cout<<"}";
    }
};


int main() {
  sumaArreglos arreglo1;
  sumaArreglos arreglo2; // no sé por qué no me funciona cuando trato de que arreglo2 sea de la clase sumar arreglo

  arreglo1.setArreglo();
  cout<<"cambio"<<endl;
  arreglo2.setArreglo();

  arreglo1.accionSumar(arreglo2);

  arreglo1.imprimir();

  return 0;
  
}
```

UPDATE II:

Respondiendo a tu comentario, si, también puedes usar un método de otro objeto externo dentro un método de la clase, mira este ejemplo, en donde en vez de acceder al array de la clase directamente utilizo un método que lo devuelve llamado `getArray()`:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class sumaArreglos{
  private:
    int arreglo[1000];
    int tamanio;
  public:
    sumaArreglos(){}
    ~sumaArreglos(){}
    void setArreglo(){
      cout<<"Digite el tamaño: "<<endl;
      cin>>tamanio;
      int numeroEntrada;
      for(int i=0; i<tamanio; i++){
        cout<<"Digite el elemento #"<<i<<endl;
        cin>>numeroEntrada;
        arreglo[i]=numeroEntrada;
      }
    }
    void accionSumar(sumaArreglos arreglo2){
      for(int i=0; i<tamanio; i++){
        arreglo[i] = arreglo[i] + arreglo2.getArray()[i];
      }
    }
    void imprimir(){
      cout<<"{";
      for(int i=0; i<7; i++){
        cout<<arreglo[i]<<" ";
      }
      cout<<"}";
    }
    int * getArray(){
        return arreglo;
    }
};


int main() {
  sumaArreglos arreglo1;
  sumaArreglos arreglo2; // no sé por qué no me funciona cuando trato de que arreglo2 sea de la clase sumar arreglo

  arreglo1.setArreglo();
  cout<<"cambio"<<endl;
  arreglo2.setArreglo();

  arreglo1.accionSumar(arreglo2);

  arreglo1.imprimir();

  return 0;
  
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, me quedó todo muy claro, no sabía que cuando se invocaba un parámetro de un tipo de dato clase la sintaxis tiene que ser parámetro.atributo.

Comment: Con gusto, no es estrictamente que tiene que ser así, si no que tienes que tomar en cuenta que un método de una clase actúa sobre el objeto que lo invoca. Entonces cuando haces ```arreglo1.accionSumar(arreglo2)```, la función ```accionSumar``` solo tiene conocimiento de ```arreglo1``` y por lo tanto puede acceder al miembro ```arreglo``` sin problema al escribir ```arreglo``` (en vez de ```arreglo1.arreglo```). Sin embargo, no es lo mismo para los miembros de ```arreglo2``` ya que este es un objeto externo al objeto que invocó el método ```accionSumar``` que es ```arreglo1```.

Comment: Si necesitas que te explique mejor puedo editar la respuesta original, para explicarte de una mejor manera.

Comment: No te preocupes, lo entiendo todo perfectamente.
Por cierto, si necesito utilizar un método de un objeto externo (ya sea de la misma o diferente clase) la sintaxis sería la misma? Es decir que se escriba de la forma objetoExterno.método como se hizo en el ejemplo (objetoExterno.atributo)?

Comment: Si, edite la respuesta para que veas un ejemplo